# looking for a random matrix of zeros and ones in python with a limited amount of ones

Tags: python, matrix, random, max

I am generating a matrix of zeros and ones in python as

```
poblacionCandidata = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(4, 2))
```

However, I need for it to be only two ones at most in each row.

I have checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61218595/generate-binary-random-matrix-with-upper-and-lower-limit-on-number-of-ones-in-ea), but it is too complex for me.

Can anyone help me with this

The result should be something like

```
[[1 1 0 0]
 [1 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0]]
```

Best regards

Comment: Are you saying that each row should contain "at most" 2 1s? i.e., could there be none?

Comment: Yes, it could be none

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use a loop:

```
import numpy as np

def generate_matrix(rows: int, cols: int, max_ones_per_row: int) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Generate a matrix with up to a specified number of ones per row.
    
    :param rows: The number of rows in the matrix.
    :param cols: The number of columns in the matrix.
    :param max_ones_per_row: The maximum number of ones to be placed in each row.
    :return: A numpy array representing the generated matrix.
    """
    matrix = np.zeros((rows, cols), dtype=int)
    for i in range(rows):
        ones_per_row = np.random.randint(0, max_ones_per_row + 1)
        ones_indices = np.random.choice(cols, ones_per_row, replace=False)
        matrix[i, ones_indices] = 1
    return matrix

poblacionCandidata = generate_matrix(rows=4, cols=4, max_ones_per_row=2)
print(poblacionCandidata)
```

**Example Output:**

```
[[1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0]]
```

Comment: Your answer seems to have always two ones in each row, not two at most

Comment: Fixed. See update.

Comment: Now it works better than mine

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I managed with creating a function

```
def generacionPoblacionCandidata(tamanioPoblacion, numColumnas, n):
    poblacionCandidata = np.zeros((tamanioPoblacion, numColumnas), dtype=int)
    for j in range(numColumnas):
        contador_unos = 0
        while contador_unos < n:
            columna_aleatoria = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=tamanioPoblacion)
            if np.sum(columna_aleatoria) <= n:
                poblacionCandidata[:, j] = columna_aleatoria
                contador_unos = np.sum(columna_aleatoria)
    return poblacionCandidata
```

I have tested it and seems to work fine

Comment: That'll be a very slow way to do what the answer you linked already does.